# What is the length of the longest strictly increasing sub-sequence of $n$ random numbers $\in R$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

***Definition)*** An event $e$ occurs *with high probability* if $\Pr(e)>1-\frac{1}{n}$.

**Tip)** $\big(O(\log{n})\big)! > n $

Let $\sigma = r_{1},r_{2},...,r_{n}$ be a sequence, such that $r_{i}$ $(1\leq i\leq n)$ is random number $\in R$.

> What is the length of the longest strictly increasing sub-sequence in $\sigma$ with high probability?

---

Let $l$ be the length of the longest strictly increasing sub-sequence in $\sigma$. Therefore, there exists at least one sub-sequence $\sigma' = r_{j+1},r_{j+2},...,r_{j+l}$, such that $r_{j+1}<r_{j+2}<...<r_{j+l}$ or $r_{j+1}>r_{j+2}>...>r_{j+l}$. The probability of occurring $\sigma'$ is $\frac{2}{l!}$.

Set $l=O(\log{n})$. Then, $\Pr\{\text{occuring }\sigma'\} = \frac{2}{\big(O(\log{n})\big)!}<\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore, $\sigma'$ does not occur with high probability, so the length of the lonest strictly increasing sub-sequence must be less than $l=O(\log{n})$.

**Is my proof correct?**

Comment: You are assuming the subsequence consists of successive elements of the sequence.  Normally it could be $r_1, r_4, r_8, r_{20}$.  You also allow decreasing subsequences, but the problem does not.

Comment: If you allow both decreasing and increasing subsequences, then there is already a monotone subsequence of length $> \sqrt{n-1}$ with probability $1$.  This is much, much longer than $O(\log n)$.

Comment: @RossMillikan The sub-sequence must consist of successive elements of the sequence. Is my question ambiguous?

Comment: Yes, I would add "contiguous" to the description.  I believe Erick Wong's comment also does not demand that the subsequences be contiguous.